# When should I send JWT refresh token?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-passport, refresh-token

I'm using JWT token for authentication with expiry of 10 minutes.
Should I send the JWT refresh token every 10 minutes and if I do that isn't that overwhelming to the server?
And how some applications don't require login more than once for lifetime when using JWT isn't that insecure?
PS: I am using Laravel passport for building JWT auth service

Comment: 10 minutes sounds like a ridiculously short time to me. Yes you need to send a refresh request every time the token expires so make the token expire after *<average time an average user needs the token for>* say 2-3 hours

Comment: @apokryfos So you are saying no matter how long the access token is valid I need to send the refresh token in a separate request every constant period of time to get new access token, Am i right ?

Comment: IMHO, If an user sends an expired token in the request, ask for refresh token, and if the user has it, it'll send you a refresh token, otherwise, assume unauthenticated and return to login page if the page needs it.

Comment: Yes, you should always try to use the token you have and request a new one if the one you have is expired/invalid. It all really depends on your use cases though. Typically JWT is used to authenticate with an API that you need to use for occasional requests, in that case setting a short expiry might be better and then always try to get a new token.